# Emacs font-lock highlighting weirdness

Tags: emacs, elisp, font-lock

I have code to change default color theme. I prefer this way because I add more classes then default `font-lock`.

```
(defmacro /construct-face (name comment &rest args)
    "Define face and specify attributes."
    (list 'progn
          (list 'defface name nil comment)
          (nconc (list 'set-face-attribute (list 'quote name) nil) args)))

(/construct-face ⋅function-name "Face to highlight functions."
                  :foreground "SlateBlue")
(setq font-lock-function-name-face '⋅function-name)
(/construct-face ⋅comment "Face to display comments"
                  :foreground "gray20"
                  :bold t)
(setq font-lock-comment-face '⋅comment)
```

Weirdness is that comment colors became gray, but function's names did not became purple. What is the difference and what should I try to check?

Comment: You're doing some weird stuff here.  Why not use builtin themes in Emacs 24?

Answer (score 0):

Because it is not "gray20" but `"grey20"`, I made this mistake yesterday as well, but with grey10.

Comment: My bad. For me it is also confusing, the use of / and some weird character ' comment...what is it?

Comment: Lisp by nature is all about symbols. I use some conventions about symbol naming to simplify highlighting. I already found solution with `copy-face`, but it seem's to be dirty hack.